# Getting Request had invalid authentication credentials error FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

Am trying to test my web push notification from postman

my app id is **thepostman-2018** so I am sending post requests to the url
`https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/thepostman-2018/messages:send`
event though I have set Authentication header and passed my **Server key**

i am getting this response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try giving token name start with 'b'. Like `bearer *********`. Might help you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the REST API over the provided SDKs?

Comment: Did you solve this? I had the key but can't get this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FCM v1 requests do not use the API key from the Firebase console to authorize requests. Instead, they use credentials retrieved by authenticating using the Service Account Key downloaded from the Firebase console. For example, this is how you generate the token using Node.js:

```
 function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var key = require('./service-account.json');
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
}
```

See the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_v1_send_requests) for more details.

Comment: Needed the `cloudmessaging.messages.create` permission on the service account for this to work. JWT class is from the `google-auth-library` package.